# Ncurses, Convert the int value to char pointer in C

Tags: c

I'm using Ncurses in C to create an input and output window. When the user types in something, I want to use `mvwprintw()` to display the string to the output window. I stored the return value of `wgetch()` in an array, how do I convert the int array to char pointer

```
/* cmd is an array already have the int value for the character,
  I declare it like char cmd[100], and store the int value return by wgetch() into 
  it*/
char realcmd[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    if (cmd[i] == 0){
         realcmd[i] = '\0';
     }
     else{
         realcmd[i] = cmd[i] + 0;
     }
}
```

This is how I convert the int array to char pointer, but I only get the first character. For example, if I type in `" hello world"`, I only get `'h'`.

Comment: I don't know about the Ncurses library or the functions you mention, but `wgetch()` apparently returns just a success flag, some integer defined as `ERR` upon failure and something else in success. Why are you storing this in an array? Why are you trying to convert it into `char`? And what does the last part of your question has anything to do with it? I cannot make a connection between the first paragraph, the code and the second paragraph. Are you sure this is not an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you call the function `mvwprintw()`?

Which format string to you use as fourth argument? It seems to me, that you use the char (`%c`) conversion qualifier instead of the string (`%s`) qualifier.

Try this:

```
mvwprintw(win, 0, 0, "%s", realcmd);
```

`mvwprintw()` use the same conversion qualifier as `printf()`. You can read this in the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mvwprintw) from `mvwprintw()`.